# Как получить запрос POST(Flask) в python

Tags: python, post, flask

Здраствуйте, пишу код не давно хотел сделать небольшое приложения с использованием запроса.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/a')
def a():
    page = request.args.get('page', default = 0, type = int)
    filter = request.args.get('filter', default = '*', type = str)
    RE = 'page: ' + str(page) + '\n' + 'filter: ' + str(filter)
    return RE

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    f = request.json()
    return f
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Делаю запрос через curl:

```
curl -H -X POST "aplication/json" {"Name": "Sasha"} "http://127.0.0.1:5000/add"
```

Вывод:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: aplication
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 7
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка??

Переписал строчку как просили:

```
$curl -X POST -H "aplication/json" -d '{"Name": "Sasha"}' "http://127.0.0.1:5000/add"

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Ошибка на сервере:

```
'The view function did not return a valid response. The'
     TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
     127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2018 18:39:38] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Поменял две строчки:

```
f = request.json()
return f
```

На:

```
f = request.get_json()
return "Add the json request."
```

Все заработало!)

Comment: У вас в curl что попало написано, почитайте его справку и составьте корректную команду

Comment: Переписал, но все равно дает ошибку только 500.

Comment: @MaxAdamchuk а теперь надо заглянуть в логи сервера, там написано с чем конкретно связана ошибка.

Comment: Спосибо, уже посмтрел и подправил)

Answer (score 3):

У вас несколько ошибок в коде и как к нему обращение идёт в curl команде.

Из-за неверной `curl` команды, заголовок Content-Type не выставляется в application/json, поэтому `request.json` возвращает None. То есть вы должны получить `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` с вашим кодом.

Даже если исправить curl команду, это только заменит ошибку на: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. Без исправления `curl` команды, `request.get_json()` также не работает (`None` по умолчанию возвращается).

Вот пример простейшего echo-приложения, которое возвращает переданный ей json текст:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/echo', methods=['POST'])
def echo():
    return jsonify(request.get_json(force=True))
```

Чтобы запустить, для теста, приложение:

```
$ FLASK_APP=app.py flask run -h localhost -p 5001
```

Пример запроса:

```
$ curl --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"key": "value"}' 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/echo'
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

Подобные запросы удобно c помощью https://httpie.org/ делать:

```
$ http --body :5001/echo key=value
{
    "key": "value"
}
```

Если сделать запрос с неверным Content-Type заголовком, то благодаря [`force=True`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json), это приложение `400 Bad Request` HTTP статус вернёт (индикация ошибочного запроса).